# -bash: flutter: command not found

Tags: flutter

I'm installing flutter, have followed all the steps in the documentation and also a online course and have set the Path in my .bash_profile file, however every time I try to run a Flutter command I get the error:

> -bash: flutter: command not found

[image]

Above screen shot of my .bash_profile file.

Here's what I am trying to run:

```
Carsons-MBP:~ carsoncarbery$ flutter doctor

-bash: flutter: command not found

Carsons-MBP:~ carsoncarbery$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/flutter/bin
```

My flutter folder is in this directory:

```
Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418192/bash-flutter-command-not-found/69477056#comment93711457_53418192) who solved this one for me. It should've been:

```
/users/
```

instead of:

```
users/
```

Answer (score 13):

On Mac OS, insert single quotes OR double quotes around the file path like below. It's better to work like this with file paths in source files:

```
export PATH="/Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/flutter/bin":$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH='/Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/flutter/bin':$PATH
```

Comment: Works for me M1 Mac

Answer (score 3):

```
export PATH=/Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing quotes fixed the problem for me. Running MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

Before:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/me/Developer/flutter/bin"
```

After:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/Developer/flutter/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

After scrambling a lot over many answers . finally I found out that we need to know which shell we are using.

So as per flutter docs,

**If you’re using Bash, edit $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc. If you’re using Z shell, edit $HOME/.zshrc.**

As I was using Bash all I did was

touch .bash_profile

open .bash_profile

add my path in .bash_profile as

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/krtrsda/flutter/bin"

run flutter command & we are good to go..

If you are using Z shell

touch ~/.zshrc

open ~/.zshrc

and then add path same as we did for .bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Catalina, open terminal, follow this step:

1. Create zshrc file: touch ~/.zshrc
2. Open file zshrc: open ~/.zshrc
3. Insert this line to file, type:
   export PATH="/Users/YOUR_NAME/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH"
   Save file and close.
   (explain: YOUR_NAME -is the name of the user your Mac,  Downloads -is a folder I put folder flutter)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution.
First of all create zshrc file, if not create already. and to see this use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

now you need to set environment path using

1. open terminal and hit command
2. `vim $HOME/.zshrc`
3. press `"I" or "i"` key for enabling inster mode.
4. add the path of your flutter sdk folder

same like the following line

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mobileprogramming/Development/sdks/flutter/bin"
```

5. Press `"Esc"` then write `:wq!` in terminal and press enter to exit editing.
6. Reopen the terminal and check `flutter doctor` or just `flutter`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this permanently(on mac), you can go to etc/paths, and set the contents to:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
"path-to-flutter-sdk-folder"/bin
```

note that that to do this, you need to go to get info, and set the permissions to read/write for etc, and paths

once it is done, you will have access to the dart command, and flutter command

finally, restart your terminal and computer.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac os use

export PATH='/Users/username/Downloads/flutter/bin':$PATH